# ASP.NET Core RC2 Identity Database Schema Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the new ASP.NET Core RC2 template (With no database available at the back-end), when I try to register a user it throws the following error for adding Migrations.

[image]

While in the past, it use to generate the database for us without adding initial migration when we run the application. Is there a way to create the database in ASP.NET Core RC2 without Initial Migration?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework core? You need Database.EnsureCreated(); https://wildermuth.com/2015/3/17/A_Look_at_ASP_NET_5_Part_3_-_EF7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing scenario you can use `context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync()` somewhere during startup. Ensure you are using [this pattern](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/src/MusicStore/Models/SampleData.cs#L22-L34) (for now) and not inject it directly in configure, to avoid issues during startup.

For future reference the code section copied from the [MusicStore](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore) example application.

```
using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    var db = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MusicStoreContext>();

    if (await db.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync())
    {
        await InsertTestData(serviceProvider);
        if (createUsers)
        {
            await CreateAdminUser(serviceProvider);
        }
    }
}
```

because at this point, there is no scope yet. If you later want to apply the migrations you can use `context.Database.AsRelational().ApplyMigrations()` ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/629#issuecomment-114571960))

Comment: Thanks. I was missing `Database.EnsureCreated()`.